# WorkManager(CoroutineWorker) - running a task periodically every 12 hours doesn't work

Tags: android-workmanager, periodic-task

I'm working on an android app,

I need to run a task periodically every 12 hours, i don't mind if its not exact, i just need the task to indeed run(I don't care even if it will run once per 15 hours, I just need to make sure it runs about every 12-24 hours)

My task is not very long, takes at most a few seconds.

From what I'v understood, WorkManager is the way to go in this case(short deferrable tasks that have to run periodically)

I have the following problem - The task seem to run the first time immediately(this is what i want), but it does not run again even after a day or more although(even if i use the app!) i'v set the delay between tasks to be 12 hours

I'm using periodic work request, and my code looks something like this:

```
val MyRequest =
       PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<MyWork>(12, TimeUnit.HOURS)
           .setInitialDelay(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
           .build()
WorkManager.getInstance(context)
          .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(TAG, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, MyRequest)
```

this code is currently called from the main activity on create

even if i close the app and open it again after 30 hours, still the work does not run,
it only runs one time, if i uninstall the app and install again, it only runs once.
when i debug i can see that the code i added runs everytime when "on create" runs, but the work does not run. If i use ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, then it works everytime, but i want the work to run once per 12 hours, and not everytime when "on create" is running, which is why i used ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP

- note that i did not set constraints, workmanager states in its documentation that the default is no constraints at all

Any idea what could be causing this or how to fix this? Was i wrong choosing WorkManager?

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55349488/work-manager-not-working-when-app-is-killed-by-the-user-why) , maybe this explains my problem?(I'm using a Samsung device)

But even if this explains the problem, it does not explain why the task is not running for a second time if i open the app after 2 days, but it does work 1 time when installing and opening it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try checking this answer from me:

[Android PeriodicWorkRequest. Which time it will execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73374538/android-periodicworkrequest-which-time-it-will-execute/73384147#73384147)

Also, you can check my profile for other answers I have about the WM. But long story short:

You need to check the JS dump and find what is the unsatisfied constrain.

And I have just answered another question that can give your more context on why WM is not that reliable to start at the time you are expecting:

[Which is better alarm manager or workmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73769178/which-is-better-alarm-manager-or-workmanager)